# How to change role of subscriber to allow them to delete a post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a front-end post editing and deleting option in my theme. Right now a subscriber cannot delete a post.  How can I change the role of a subscriber to allow them to delete a post?

I have read this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277937/wordpress-get-delete-post-link-not-working-for-custom-role) but did not get anything from it. Maybe some guidance on it will work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Go to settings => General => New User Default Role
```

change user role from here

Comment: OMG I dont know why since last month I am trying to do everything by coding even if there are simple settings through Dashboard. Whatever I have lost my 4 points. Thanks

Comment: its okay.. you will earn points later :)